# Can't view source in IE8 & VS2008

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2008, internet-explorer-8

I need to see what's rendered from my aspx page. When I publish, some features aren't working.

However, when I hit F5 from the IDE, my features work fine.

So I figure, why not view the source from the published website and compare it to development.

Problem is, when I hit F5 from the IDE and get IE8 -- 'view source' is disabled.

How can this be solved?

Comment: have you tried viewing it in firefox and using firebug?

Comment: Are you using ajax in the page? You can't view source on an ajax page.
Also, check if you are missing any files in the publish directory with your development.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It could be that your IE cache/Temporary Internet Files is 'full'. Try clearing your IE cache and Temp Internet Files, etc. Some other ways to [determine your cache is full if IE doesn't allow you to View Source](http://www.webmasterworld.com/forum10/3362.htm)

> Try saving any image off any site. Does the file name default to "image.bmp" or "*.bmp"? If it does then your cache is definitely full.

Some other tweaks while you're in there to help debugging, especially the 'Every time I visit...'!

[image]